# Fetch records of a table as an array php mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

The query is:

How can I fetch the abbr from manualtab into an array. Code:

```
 $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('Unable to connect!');
 mysql_select_db('mydb') or die ('Unable to select database!');
 $query = 'SELECT abbr FROM manualtab';
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error in query');
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this code? Are you getting an error? Are you just getting nothing in `$row`?

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to get all of the records into one array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
  $array[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, fetching every abbr in an array, then:

```
$abbr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $abbr[] = $row[0];
}
```

is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

That does the job, unless you want to fetch all values, in which case you'll need to loop:

```
 $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('Unable to connect!');
 mysql_select_db('mydb') or die ('Unable to select database!');
 $query = 'SELECT abbr FROM manualtab';
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error in query');
 $row_list = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $row_list[] = $row;
 }

 var_dump($row_list);
     /* row_list now contains:
     array(
        array( 'abbr' => ... ),
        array( 'abbr' => ... ),
        array( 'abbr' => ... ),
            ...
     ) */
```